# How to make a custom SettingsPane look like the permissions in the Settings Charm Windows 8

Tags: windows, windows-8, microsoft-metro

I have created a custom Settings Charm options for "About" in my win8 app. I would like the style to look like the Permissions pane. Is the best way to just hardcode these values or is there a way to make it set to the default.

Current Look:
[image]

Desired Look:
[image]

This is where I got my example code: 
http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/App-settings-sample-1f762f49

Answer (score 0):

In App.xaml.cs, create color variables

```
private SolidColorBrush _background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0xFF, 0x00, 0x3E, 0x00));
 // FF003E00
private SolidColorBrush _Hbackground = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromArgb(0xEE, 0x00, 0x8A, 0X00));
```

Now, when you are creating the settings menu for permissions,

```
private void OnCommandsRequested(SettingsPane sender, SettingsPaneCommandsRequestedEventArgs args)
    {
        var Permissions= new SettingsCommand("Permissions", "Permissions", (handler) =>
            {
                var settings = new SettingsFlyout();
                settings.Content = new AboutUserControl();
                //settings.HeaderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(_background);
                //settings.Background = new SolidColorBrush(_background);
                settings.HeaderBrush = _Hbackground;
                settings.Background = _background;
                settings.HeaderText = "Permissions";
                settings.IsOpen = true;
            });

        args.Request.ApplicationCommands.Add(Permissions);

        UICommandInvokedHandler handler1 = new UICommandInvokedHandler(onSettingsCommand);

        //  throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
```

So as you can see you can set the header background color as well as the body background color. With this code, you can set the color of your choice for the settings menu

Answer (score -2):

if you are taking about the Background color, than you can define a global Background color in StandardStyles.xaml or App.xaml to use it everywhere. You don't have access to System theme color information so you do have to hardcode it.